# How to use IME Pad in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, unicode, ime

I´m trying to develope a C# WPF application that displays the Microsoft Input Method Editor Pad in order to be able to enter single Unicode characters directly without the necessity of using a keyboard (a stripped version of the IME Pad that can be embedden inside my WPF App however would be ideal - if I´m somehow able to achieve this).
Unfortunately I´m still a student and relatively new to C# programming. It seems I´m not even able to get the Pad started programmatically.
A simple

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\IME\shared\IMEPADSV.EXE");`

Does not seem to work (but also throws no error).

The documentaions I´ve found so far are describing the C++ Interfaces IIMEPad, IIMEPadApplet, IMEActiveDict and IImeSpecifyApplets.

Eg.

- http://blog.yezhucn.com/dnime/imepadif.htm
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee828915%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Maybe there´s someone out there who is able to show me an example how it is possible to start the Pad programmatically, or how the C++ Interfaces can be accessed in C# in order to use or even modify the Pad.

Thank you for your time :)

Sam